# JSON: parseInt does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code in which I try to sum up count values that come from a JSON object. It is not possible for me to convert the count into an integer:

```
var obj = {
  "Person1": {
    "element1": 323,
    "element2": 123,
    "element3": 123
  },
  "Person2": {
    "element4": 56,
    "element5": 234,
    "element6": 566
  },
}

$.each(obj, function (key, values) {
                            var totalCount = '';
                            $.each(values, function(person, count) {
                                totalCount += parseInt(count);
                            });

                            console.log(totalCount);
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/u43cw49m/

What am I doing wrong? Why does parseInt not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined totalCount as a string. Just change var totalCount = ''; to

```
var totalCount = 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u43cw49m/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is because of this line :

```
var totalCount = '';
```

That should be

```
var totalCount = 0;
```

else you code seems good and works fine, but not your fiddle which doesn't have the `parseInt()` call...